# Correct way to check zookeeper's running mode

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Can someone let me know what is the recommended way to check zookeeper's running mode via netcat?

The documentation states `echo "isro" | nc localhost 2181`

But in few [links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28424409/785523) it is recommended to use `-q` with netcat

Can someone let me know is it needed to use `-q` is needed?

- Zookeeper Version 3.4.13
- OS - Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the netcat version you have. If you type nc you will see the available supported flags. For example,

```
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT] - listen

-e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
-l Listen mode, for inbound connects
-lk With -e, provides persistent server
-p PORT Local port
-s ADDR Local address
-w SEC Timeout for connects and final net reads
-i SEC Delay interval for lines sent
-n Don’t do DNS resolution
-u UDP mode
-v Verbose
-o FILE Hex dump traffic
-z Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
```

It does not have the -q option. The -q flag is used to wait for x seconds for a response to come back from the server. This usually helps to give some x seconds for the server to respond and reduce false positives if any. So if your netcat version still supports it, I would suggest to use it.

On the same note, apart from checking the running mode ("ro" if in read-only mode or "rw" if not in read-only mode), I would suggest using **zkServer.sh status** command and grep the **Mode** to see in which mode an instance is running. In a cluster, the zookeeper runs as either a leader or a follower. So this enhances the healthcheck and guarantees that the zookeeper cluster is running (in ro or rw) as well as it is in a quorum.

Comment: zkServer.sh status uses 'srvr' four-letter-word command which can be also used directly with netcat. However I recommend moving from 4LW to JMX commands as it has become deprecated in recent ZK versions.

Comment: @AndorMolnar Where did you see the 4LW get deprecated? zkServer.sh by default whitelists `srvr` command and if we want to use other 4LW, we can use the property `4lw.commands.whitelist` to whitelist all or required 4lw.
Can you please share the reference where it says its deprecated as I still see it is still getting used in the official zookeeper 3.6.2 doc https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.2/zookeeperAdmin.html

Comment: I'm member of Zookeeper PMC, but it's true we didn't announce this officially. Generally speaking we don't accept patches for 4LW's anymore, because Jetty is the preferred way of administering ZK nodes. Although 4LWs are still present.